# jQuery Ajax and XSL

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml, xslt

Could I ask what could possible be a stupid question.

I currently use an asp.Net framework to pull data from a sqlService DB in xml format and then shape it using xsl. I’m interested in using ajax to do a few of the takes that I’m currently doing with a standard .net/xml/xsl deal. Is it possible to use xsl with jQuery/Ajax? Like I say, could be a stupid question, but thought I would ask anyhow. Big thanks. Andy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for [**jQuery XSLT Plugin**](http://www.jongma.org/webtools/jquery/xslt/#license_ajaxslt)